# only last row of the database display repeatedly in jsp page

Tags: java

this is home servlet to display the list of data in jsp(java server page).I am not able to display my database table rows,instead of which the last row of the database was displayed repeatedly upto the total number of database rows.

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String address = "balaju";
    request.setAttribute("address", address);//response can not use

    //ItemBean item = new ItemBean();

    List<ItemBean> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
    try {
        System.out.println("at home servlet");
        ItemDao dao = ItemDaoFactory.getItemDao();
        itemList = dao.getItemFromdb();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("@home servlet ");
    for(ItemBean item1:itemList){
        System.out.println(item1.getTransactionTime());
        System.out.println(item1.getItemPrice());
        System.out.println(item1.getItemName());
    }
    request.setAttribute("itemList", itemList);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home/home.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);}
```

//jdbc code intend to display list of data form database but only the last row of database is displaye  in the jsp page using jstl foreach tag

```
 public List<ItemBean> getItemFromdb() throws SQLException {
    JdbcConnection connecton = new JdbcConnection();
    String query = "select * from itemsinfo";
    //Connection con = connecton.getConnection();
    List<ItemBean> itemList = new ArrayList<ItemBean>();
    ItemBean item = new ItemBean();
    Statement statement = connecton.getSqlStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
       rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
         while (rs.next()) {


            item.setItemName(rs.getString("itemname"));
            item.setItemPrice(rs.getDouble("itemprice"));
            item.setTransactionTime(rs.getString("transactiontime"));
           // itemList.add(item);

           /* System.out.println("itemname :"+item.getItemName());
            System.out.println("price:"+item.getItemPrice());
            System.out.println("time:"+item.getTransactionTime());
            System.out.println("/n"); */

        }

        System.out.println("at jdbc code");
        for(ItemBean item1:itemList){

            System.out.println(item1.getItemName());
            System.out.println(item1.getItemPrice());
            System.out.println(item1.getTransactionTime());
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return itemList;

}
```

Comment: why have you commented out code to add item to itemList in getItemFromdb()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one Item in your List.

```
 // ItemBean item = new ItemBean(); // You don't need this one.
 while (rs.next()) {
   ItemBean item = new ItemBean(); // Instantiate a new ItemBean, don't update ONE.
   item.setItemName(rs.getString("itemname"));
   item.setItemPrice(rs.getDouble("itemprice"));
   item.setTransactionTime(rs.getString("transactiontime"));
   itemList.add(item); // Add the item to the List.
 }
```

Comment: @JigarJoshi It *was* commented out. I assume it should be added to the List so I uncommented it, I further assumed **multiple** item(s) should be added. Without a `new ItemBean()` in the while loop, that wasn't happening.

Comment: OH! MY GOD .......success ...thank to all of you.If you guys help me like that I can go next chapter.Unexpected great help.It was my first question got help...especially thank to  @Elliott Frisch